# Ruby email encoding and quoted-printable content

Tags: ruby, email, tmail

Is there a straightforward way to coach TMail to make the body encoded with "quoted-printable"? I only see methods in there for decoding content like that, not creating it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you just using `TMail`, or are you using it with `ActionMailer`? It looks like `TMail` itself does not have the ability to encode as `quoted-printable`. However, it looks like `ActionMailer` does have this ability.

It looks like `TMail` allows you to set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header as follows :-

```
mail = TMail::Mail.new
mail.transfer_encoding = "quoted-printable"
```

But it looks like this doesn't actually encode the body.

You can see `ActionMailer` setting this header [here](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8fdf3d7890d2e58508e028c93d3797f21a774dbc/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/part.rb#L44). `quoted-printable` seems to be the default for `ActionMailer`.

`ActionMailer` has the [ActionMailer::Quoting::quoted_printable](http://github.com/rails/rails/blob/8fdf3d7890d2e58508e028c93d3797f21a774dbc/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/quoting.rb#L5) method to encode the body as `quoted-printable`. Maybe you can make use of this...?

Comment: It seems that these days, you'd use Mail::Encodings::QuotedPrintable.encode