# Encode mail as quoted-printable before sending in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, actionmailer, quoted-printable

I saw this question and couldn't make use of it:
[Ruby email encoding and quoted-printable content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034135/ruby-email-encoding-and-quoted-printable-content)

I'd like to send out email as quoted-printable, but it's going out as unencoded `text/html`. Any help?

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome_mail(user)
    recipients        user.email
    from              "no-reply@example.com"
    subject           "Thanks for registering"
    body              :user => user
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution posted on [Ruby Quiz](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz23.html).